# IIS 7.5 connection problems

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, freeze

In the last couple of weeks my site has hung.  Connections increase but seem to never release.  Once it hits 700+ current connections (using the performance tool) the whole site hangs and I have no choice but to do iisreset to get it working again.  Normally it's around 100 concurrent connections at peak time.  No errors or warnings in the event log when it stops releasing so that isn't helpful.  This problem has been happening after copying new DLLs over the old ones to do a site update.  I have a single server so no choice but to copy over live.  But in the case of today it was fine after the update but then the problem happened two hours later. It's .NET 4.5 site on Windows 2008 R2 64bit.  Is there a way I can find out what's causing this, like other log files some place or something I should try doing when it happens?  What I have tried is recycling the app pool (doesn't help), turning off the app pool and back on (doesn't turn on, gives exception), restarting the site (doesn't help), and iisreset (works every time).

Comment: i have similar issues, for me its a web-farm with 5 servers, and when connection goes up to 6k per server, site will literally crawl, and cpu goes to 100%..IIS reset of 3 of the servers solve it, but hard to pin point the cause..

Answer (score 2):

Usually some requests are "stuck" when you see these syndromes, as app.pool recycle and site restart will wait for the pending requests to finish in general (graceful exit), while iisreset will actually kill the w3wp.exe process after 20 (or 30?) seconds if it doesn't exit on its own (non-graceful exit), this why iisreset works for you.

Listing the active requests (appcmd.exe list request /?) should give you a clue about why is this happening.